# What tools can we use to visualise volume integrations?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

What tools do people use to visualize integrated volumes? I'm horrible at drawing perspectives, especially with hollowed-out 3D graphs. Can't imagine how to do that going beyond the usual three dimensions.

I've tried wolfram alpha, desmos and googling for tools but can't seem to find anything that can actually map out the integration. Does something like this exist?

Comment: *Mathematica*..

Comment: Why do you think you need a good visual to solve the problem? In physics I just use blobs with directions and solve the problems just fine.